# IOS: How to implement MFSideMenu in iOS Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, menu

i am working in a project in which i want a right side menu. For Right Side menu i am using `MFSideMenu`. I  Added the `MFSideMenu` folder to my project and also Added QuartzCore to project but its not working 
Please suggest me some codes as i need only right Side Menu in my project.
It shows an error "MFSideMenu.h" not found

in my AppDelegate i added

```
#import "MFSideMenu.h"

MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score -1):

Just go through the following link:
https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu
It will help you to integrate MFSidemenu along with all variations and pitfall.